# What should I do if my department head encourages us to do questionable practices to raise publication indices?

Tags: publications

In our departmental staff meeting, we were encouraged by the head to practice salami slicing and to require authors of the papers we review to cite our own papers. What should I do in this case? What is likely to happen if I express my disagreement? I am a junior member of the faculty.

Comment: "In academia, salami slicing refers to the practice of creating several short publications out of material that could have, perhaps more validly, been published as a single article in a journal or review."

Comment: "In the academic justice system, salami-based offenses are considered especially heinous. In most universities, the dedicated detectives who investigate these vicious felonies are members of an elite squad known as the Special Proctors Unit. These are their stories. DUN DUN"

Answer (score 3):

This is scientific misconduct. First, you are responsible for yourself. In your situation I would not follow these practices since it can (and probably will) have bad consequences for you.

However, you should address your concerns. Almost every university has a person who is responsible for scientific integrity. Sometimes he/she is called ombudsman. Have a talk with them. Try to do this in an anonymous way, otherwise I would fear the consequences.

Comment: I never heard of that. Slicing results in several papers? I dont think so.

Comment: @SSimon  I know of a guy who milks 10 papers out of material for 2.  He publishes the first paper, containing the bare minimum needed.  The next paper cuts a bit off the front and adds a bit to the end.  Repeat as needed.  Each paper is supposedly the natural follow up to the one before.  But you could take the first and last papers and read them back to back with no loss of continuity.

Comment: yes, @B.Goddard I agree with you, but why is that misconduct?

Comment: @SSimon Slicing may not be misconduct, but it's sleazy.  Forcing someone to cite your paper, instead of reviewing their paper honestly, is misconduct.  But the real misconduct is the chair making such practices policy.

Comment: @B.Goddard and government awarding those scientists.